# Is it possible to trigger input/change event when something is changed in input type="date"?

Tags: javascript, events, input

```js
let date = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
date.addEventListener('input',function(){
  console.log('input');
});
```

```html
<input type="date">
```

```js
let date = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
date.addEventListener('change',function(){
  console.log('change');
});
```

```html
<input type="date">
```

They are the same code, I just used two different event types.

Problem is, event fires out when all three parts of date are changed. For example if I have yyyy-mm-21 or 2020-04-dd event doesn't fire.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

here says there are only these two events which input type="date" understands. How should I do if I want to trigger event at every time when I change something in date?

and please
NO JQUERY

Comment: @caramba sorry, date, I will edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can be a little creative with all the "change" events which exist. Depending on what you want to do on every event. This is just to show some options, obviously you can assign what ever functionality needed for every event.

```js
let date = document.querySelector('input[type="date"]');

let myAwesomeFunction = function(event){
  console.log('event.type: ', event.type, ' value: ', event.target.value );
};

date.addEventListener('change', myAwesomeFunction);
date.addEventListener('click', myAwesomeFunction);
date.addEventListener('keyup', myAwesomeFunction);
date.addEventListener('keydown', myAwesomeFunction);
date.addEventListener('blur', myAwesomeFunction);
date.addEventListener('focus', myAwesomeFunction);
date.addEventListener('focusout', myAwesomeFunction);
```

```html
<input type="date">
```

Unfortunately you don't get a value until all fields (day, month, year) are set. (Please comment if someone has a solution for that)

Comment: @gamelover glad it helped! happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Use `onkeyup` to fire on every key and `onchange` to fire when user selects the date from the picker.

```js
let date = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
date.addEventListener('keyup',function(){
  console.log('keyup');
});
date.addEventListener('change',function(){
  console.log('change');
});
```

```html
<input type="date">
```

Comment: oh, never knew that I can use keyup because https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date says there are only two events, change and input. Thanks